# How can I avoid the changing of v to υ when writing lemmas?

Tags: theorems, proofreading

I'm using variables `u`, `v`, `w` in a lemma. However my latex compiler changes `v` to `υ` which then makes it difficult to distinguish between `u` and `υ`.

Why does it do this and how can I avoid it from happening?

I'm following the simple lemma format:

```
\begin{lemma}
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
\end{proof}
```

EDIT:
After David's comment, I simplified my document to point out the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{s}
\author{author}
\date{November 2014} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{lemma}
Let $u$, $v$, $w$
\label{lemma4}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: latex does not change v to upsilon unless you instruct it to do so, (and actually I can not think of a convenient way of instructing it to do that) please give a _complete_ small document that shows the problem.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your comment. I added the code that gives me this problem.

Comment: the math variables there are the same math italic as you would see in the rest of the document, the lemma is irrelevant isn't it? it is an italic v as is standard for mathematics, not an upsilon

Comment: Is it possible to use v as it is? Because it makes it very hard to tell the difference between υ and u then.

Comment: You could use \mathrm{v} but be going against all mathematics typesetting tradition

Comment: This is just the italic form of "v". I do not believe you can change this behaviour since it inherent to the font. Plus it is standard typography, anyway.

Comment: thank you for your help, unfortunately I will have to change the variable names

Comment: You can use a different font. For example, you can use `newtxmath`, i.e. `\usepacakge{newtxmath}` (and times font, i.e., `\usepackage{newtxtext}`) where the shape of u and v in italic is more distinct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

the "curly" form of "v" has long been standard in mathematical typesetting
to distinguish it from the greek "nu".  the "w" is also changed for consistent style.

i've simplified your example a bit and added instances of nu and upsilon
to show the difference.

[image: output of example code]

it is essential in math that each letter be recognizable *by itself*, with no
additional context, to avoid misinterpretation.  math fonts are specially designed
precisely for this reason.  (this is also the reason why many uppercase greek
letters are not supported by tex -- because the shapes are identical to those in the latin alphabet.)

Comment: I've never found `$v$` and `\upsilon` very easy to distinguish and generally avoid ever using `\upsilon`.  And I think in a casual read, `$w$` and `\omega` can be easily mistaken too (though, if you get used to a particular font, `$w$` and `\omega` are distinguishable).

Comment: @A.Ellett -- good point.  forgot about omega; added it.  thanks.  of course, a "real" reason that these letters are difficult to distinguish from one another is that they all ultimately come from the same writing tradition, based on the [phoenician alphbet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenician_alphabet).

Answer (score 5):

If you're open to using a different math font try adding `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` to your preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{lemma}
Let $u$, $v$, $w$
\label{lemma4}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, when using Times Roman italics, someone's going to complain that `$v$` and `$\nu$` look too similar...

Comment: @Mico are you calling barbara _someone_ :-)

Comment: @Mico -- after a noodge because my answer was just now accepted, i saw your comment.  when times was used "in production" for math texts, the times "v" was traditionally substituted by that letter from a century font (i think schoolbook) to avoid the confusion with "nu", and "w" was also substituted to harmonize with the "v".  i don't know for sure whether this was done just for math, or was also used in the text.  but possibly both, since it would have been easier to handle on monotype.